# Transpose with default headers in excel

Tags: excel

I have a simple data which is

```
Name   Age
Venky   20
Anil    22
```

Output should be like :

```
Name : Venky
Age  : 20
Name : Anil
Age  : 22
```

Note : For each record should have header values

I have tried multiple ways apart from Macros
Can you please give me you inputs?

Comment: Is possible with macros and, I think, wth formulas, but you can share at least one screenshot with data format and results?
Thanks

Comment: To start with: you have one time the headers "Name" and "Age" and you want them multiple times. In top of that, you want the data to be set on one line. In order to get this done, you'll need to write a macro indeed.

Comment: @Dominique Could you please give me some inputs will write the query

Comment: @VenkatT  based on your input in your question I provided a solution, please review it and mark is as correct if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific context from the question, we can combine [BYROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb), [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01), [TOCOL](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-tocol-function#:%7E:text=The%20TOCOL%20function%20transforms%20an,skipping%20empty%20cells%20and%20errors.), `TEXTJOIN`, `TEXTSPLIT` and `SUBSTITUTE` to get the expected result (adding the link since some of them are relatively new Excel functions):

```
=LET(y,SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(";",,
  BYROW(A2:C4, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(";",,MAP(TOCOL(A1:C1), TOCOL(x), 
  LAMBDA(a,b, a & ":"& b & ";")))))), ";;",";"), 
  TEXTSPLIT(LEFT(y, LEN(y) - 1),,";"))
```

The main idea is create on the fly for **each row** of input data(`A1:B3` including the headers) a new array via `MAP` with the following structure (let’s call it `tempArray`:

```
| Name:name1; |
|-------------|
| Age:age1;   |
```

**Note**: It works for more than two columns in the header, if that is the case a row per header item will be created.

For example:

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A1:B1), TOCOL(A2:B2), LAMBDA(a,b, a & ":"& b & ";"))
```

For the first row of the input data will return:

```
| Name:Venky; |
| ------------|
| Age:10;     |
```

Then convert `tempArray` into a text via: `TEXTJOIN` so every element of `BYROW`, i.e. `x` is converted to a string, where each record is delimited by `;`. For the first row it will be:

```
Name:Venky;;Age:10;
```

`SUBSTITUTE` is used to remove the extra `;` generated by `TEXTJOIN`. For example for the first row it would be:

```
Name:Venky;Age:10;
```

After executing `SUBSTITUTE` the intermediate result would be:

```
Name:Venky;Age:20;Name:Anil;Age:22;
```

We use `LEFT` to remove the extra `;` at the end. Now we have a string that has each row delimited by `;`, so the string is ready to be converted back to an array using `TEXTSPLIT`.

Sample adding an additional record and **Last Name** as a new header item:

[image: sample excel file]